# Using Linq to populate a class

Tags: linq

I am getting a weird behavior.  I have a class that I created that is used to format data comping from a data entity into a data grid.  I am a using a linq query to create a list of the class type from a list of the entity type.  Some of the properties of the class are accessible from the linq query but other give me an error.  (AMNotStartedPortalDisplay' does not contain a definition for 'ChecklistStatusID').  So my question is why can linq access some properties but not others?  I see no reason why this should be happening.

Here is my class:

```
public class AMWOTPortalDisplay
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string LOB { get; set; }
    public string DisplayProjectPackages { get; set; }
    public string ChecklistStatus { get; set; }
    public int ChecklistStatusID { get; set; }
    public string InstallDate { get; set; }
    public string dateToYellow { get; set; }
    public string dateToRed { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationManager { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationManagerLanID { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationManagerUserID { get; set; }
    public string ImpersonatedManager { get; set; }
    public string ImpersonatedManagerLanID { get; set; }
    public int ImpersonatedManagerUserID { get; set; }
    public string DelegateName { get; set; }
    public string DelegateLanID { get; set; }
    public int DelegateUserID { get; set; }
    public string WOTAssignee { get; set; }
    public int ChecklistID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayLinkText { get; set; }
    public string LinkTextURL { get; set; }
    public string rowColor { get; set; }
    public string rowTextColor { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the linq query as I have it so far:

```
var portaldisplay = checklists
        .Select(c => new AMNotStartedPortalDisplay
        {
            DisplayName = string.Format("{0} ({1})", c.Application.Name, c.Application.ApplicationID),
            LOB = c.Application.LOB,
            ChecklistStatus = c.ChecklistStatusType.TypeName,
            ChecklistStatusID = c.ChecklistStatusTypeID



        });
```

Thanks,

Rhonda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful with your types:

```
public class AMWOTPortalDisplay
```

And then:

```
Select(c => new AMNotStartedPortalDisplay { ... })
```

It looks like your query should probably be:

```
Select(c => new AMWOTPortalDisplay { ... })
```

Comment: Oh Good grief!  It must be Monday.  Two different people looked at this and didn't see that.  Thanks.